# Very slow code for simulation of optical emission (Raman) spectra

Tags: python, performance, spectra

Can anyone help me optimise my code? It currently takes up to 15 minutes to run a calculation, and I know it should be possible in less than 10 seconds as this is what was previously achieved in Mathematica for something very similar. I need to simulate many spectra, so I need a much faster performance.

I have written a simple code to simulate a type of optical emission spectrum (Raman scattering) for different molecules. These Raman spectra are characterised by a wavelength of emission and a signal intensity.

I am dealing with a complex molecule with many spectral lines (3.5 million), which can make the code described below become very slow.

My problem occurs when converting a **stick spectrum** (i.e. pairs of wavelengths and intensities) to a **simulated spectrum** that takes into account the spectral resolution of the spectrometer. By applying the spectrometer resolution in the simulation, each discrete spectral line at a specific wavelength becomes a distribution of light intensity over a range of wavelengths. The lineshape of each line is a normal (Gaussian) distribution. Once the lineshape is calculated, the sum of intensities of every spectral line at a respective wavelengths is calculated in order to determine an overall spectrum.

This set of equations to convert from a line to a stick spectrum is given below:

```
vlow  = 2800.0 #cm-1
vhigh = 3050.0 #cm-1
dv    =    1 #cm-1
resolution = 2. #cm-1
wavelength = np.arange(vlow,vhigh,dv)

def gauss(wavelength,v0,resolution):
    I = np.exp(-((v0-wavelength)/(2*resolution))**2)
    I /= np.sum(I*dv)
    return I

I = np.zeros(len(wavelength))

def simulate(linelist):
    if simulate_spec == True:
        for line in linelist:
            wn_line,sig_line = line
            a = ((wn_line-vlow)  % dv)/dv
            b = int((wn_line-vlow) // dv)
            if b>=0 and b<=len(I)-2:    
                I[b  ] += sig_line * (1-a)
                I[b+1] += sig_line *    a

            halfwayvelength = 0.5*(wavelength[0]+wavelength[-1])
            Iconv = np.convolve(I,gauss(wavelength, halfwayvelength,
            resolution)*dv,'same')

    return(wavelength,Iconv)
```

I simply then apply the simulate function to a list of data, and a spectra is generated.

Sample data is given here:

```
[2988.051201, 2.1528594547391786],
[2965.874737, 9.832493405930505],
[2803.2158010000003, 0.00041319356649735474],
[2825.751201, 2.695035803386361e-06],
[2999.060832, 4.306173915906166],
[2826.208982, 0.00034324344563385156],
[2849.130431, 4.14575931249117e-06],
[2916.502513, 8.227955023939035e-07],
[3019.955186, 4.1128004082464935],
[2864.1083719999997, 4.7168887436524236e-07],
[2967.5610460000003, 2.3584443718262116],
[3011.59334, 8.484855475132457e-06],
[3013.1311739999996, 0.0017841866237857066],
[2810.959775, 1.6278821649562382e-05],
[2824.372448, 8.1122568270338e-06],
[2997.864286, 2.152180604795494],
[3044.539569, 0.000536291455511021],
[2966.429826, 3.932154056795204],
[3013.105109, 0.000979839907319629],
[2855.130571, 0.001800236014966169],
[2946.900868, 5.792331072221127],
[2992.882515, 0.016941583295928393],
[2830.159341, 4.1885065256659556e-05],
[2850.825762, 5.1388969852984256e-05],
[2916.542136, 5.781541962764192e-06],
[3018.591801, 3.0706663183839553],
[2843.208214, 6.239525546259207e-06],
[2945.257879, 3.3138244296836072],
[2991.205655, 0.0003465527450543083],
[2993.135932, 0.004361954391985438],
[2841.004186, 0.0008298581247320486],
[2849.245868, 0.00018996099882164256],
[2870.293698, 1.4363019628341073e-05],
[2875.746432, 2.100659304108956e-05],
[3039.611398, 1.0057174209518613],
[3041.328008, 5.840788673645993],
[2817.899557, 8.412353568584454e-05]
```

Comment: Could you confirm (1) the indentation is the same here as in your real code and (2) how frequently you need to compute Iconv?  At the moment it looks you're computing an Iconv value after every line and then throwing the result away, only using it after the last iteration.

Comment: Indentation is off for the last line of code, I will correct now.

Comment: Hi DSM. based on your comment I realised that there was a mistake. As you said I am iterating Iconv every line and it is totally unnecessary. Everything runs much faster now! Runtime is down to about 30 seconds now, which is definitely acceptable performance.